Error: TypeError: a.providers is undefined web3 ethers
i have my website deployed on vercel and using react framework. i am trying to create a web3 dapp that uses zksync paymaster. in the docs it says
import { Signer, Web3Provider } from "zksync-ethers";
import * as ethers from "ethers";

const signer = Web3Provider.getSigner

rawTx = Apiresponse.txData

//since the API returns the transaction payload in the ethers format, we can use it as is

txHash = await signer.sendTransaction(rawTx);


for my specifc use. i have it set as
      const apiResponse = await postTransactionData(payload); // Send payload to zyfi API
      const txData = apiResponse.txData; // Extract txData from API response
      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const signer = provider.getSigner();
      const txHash = await signer.sendTransaction(txData); // Send transaction using txData

      console.log("Transaction Hash:", txHash); // Log the transaction hash
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error); // Log any errors
    }
  };

but with countless debugging it still doesnt work i have tried all the recommendations on stackoverflow. i am just trying to deploy a website not a smart contract
i tried changing
import { ethers } from "ethers";

to
const ethers = require("ethers");

i also tried just like this
const signer = Web3Provider.getSigner(); 

and
const provider = new ethers.providers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum);

and this
const provider = new ethers.providers.BrowserProvider();

but it all keeps on failing with this error in console
Error: TypeError: a.providers is undefined
    onPress App.js:40
    React 18
        Le
        He
        Fn
        Fn
        Dn
        Wn
        ll
        Re
        Wn
        qt
        Vt
        Gn
        jn
        zn
        zn
        a
        $l
        render
    <anonymous> index.js:6
    <anonymous> index.js:10
    <anonymous> index.js:10

some other info. i am trying to do this on zksync and have only as my imports
import * as ethers from "ethers"; but dont have import { Signer, Web3Provider } from "zksync-ethers"; since it givescauses my deploymemt to fail since its not in use in the code.
